# Server - Knowing which scripts are running, and their memory usage

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I have quite large application, and now I'm seeing there's a bad memory leak, is there some sort of software, or something which allows me to see the current executed scripts and their size?
I'm using apache if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen `top(1)`? The `M` key will sort by memory usage. Pay most attention to the `RSS` column, it shows you the Resident Set Size of the process -- roughly how much RAM the process is taking up.

Comment: the thing which takes most memory is /usr/sbin/httpd.event... I can also see it spawns alot of /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/vhosts/drawpr.com/etc/php.ini

Comment: That sounds like you're running PHP as a [standard CGI handler](http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php). You might want to either use [`mod_php`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php) or, much better, [`FastCGI`](http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#PHP). That should help reduce system load. To hunt memory leaks in your PHP programs use [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). Good luck!